# Monero mining software

Tags: miners

I have just started mining and I found that every miner that I download is not running, blocked by chrome, or blocked by antivirus. 
Right now I'm using minergate and I don't like it.
I want some mining software. 
Please don't tell the ones on Linux because my cpu (ryzen) isn't supported by Linux, any Linux.
I don't care if it is cli or gui.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many are getting falsely flagged by antiviruses because the code from them has been copied over to some worms which also mine Monero on infected machines.

There's a nice list and guide [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/MoneroMining/wiki/index/windows-pool)

Answer (score 2):

You can use any miner which supports cryptonight algorithm.
ccminer, cpuminer comes to mind, both supports cryptonight.
Minergate's miner is actually a moded cgminer, and their blog is actually quite helpful, but there are suspicions that their software is skimming hash rates, I personally don't use any closed source miners.
The ultimate solution would be running Linux, just wait a couple of months till the proper firmware from AMD and new kernels get released then you can try again.